# Sum of nth term

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Question: find the sum of n terms whose general term is $(n^2+5n+4)(n^2+5n+8)$
I have 2 questions:

Q1: Why we take $\sum 1=n$

Q2: I have solved it by taking sigma of all terms- method i.e.
$S_n= \sum n^4+10\sum n^3+ 37\sum n^2+60\sum n+ 32 \sum 1$
can this question be solved by summation formula i.e.
$S_n= \frac{(\text{nth term} \;\cdot\; \text{next factor})}{(\text{no: of factors in each term}+1)\;\cdot\;c.d} + C$,    (c.d stands for common differece in sequence)if yes then let me know the solution.

thanks.

Comment: Please read about how to express mathematical notation here at StackExchange.

Comment: I tried but unable to understand that how MathJax would be used during writing a question.

Comment: Here you go: meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference